# Json Multiset vs ArrayList

Tags: java, json, arraylist, multiset

I have `Multiset<String>` objects, which I am serializing as Json. I am doing this using Gson as follows:

```
Multiset<String> mset = ... ;
Gson gson = new Gson();
Files.write(Gson.toJson(mset), new File(abosulte_path_string), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

When I try to deserialize it, I do the following:

```
String json_string = ... // read from file
Type type = new TypeToken<Multiset<String>>(){}.getType();
Multiset<String> treated = gson.fromJson(json_string, type);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.google.common.collect.Multiset
```

When I opened the json file, I see that the `Multiset<String>` object is, indeed, represented as an ArrayList ([string1, string2, ... ]), with repetitions for strings that had `count > 1` in the multiset.

I can, of course, cast it into an ArrayList and then use the `create(Iterable<>)` constructor to get my multiset, but it seems to be a roundabout way. Is there a more direct way of deserializing the json object to retrieve my multisets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** It looks like in this case there is a much easier way to solve this problem, namely by registering an [instance creator](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator) for Multisets:

```
private static class MultisetInstanceCreator implements InstanceCreator<Multiset<?>> {
    @Override
    public Multiset<?> createInstance(Type type) {
        return HashMultiset.create();
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Multiset.class, new MultisetInstanceCreator())
        .create();
```

The instance creator just defines how a Multiset should be created, since the Guava collections don't have default constructors (and Multiset is the interface anyway).

**Original answer:** I'm not sure if this is the best or easiest way to achieve what you want, but it is one way that worked for us recently for a similar problem (in our case it was deserialising to an ImmutableMap).

The basic idea is to register a [custom deserialiser](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) which basically does what you already discovered as a possible solution: deserialise to an ArrayList, then turn it into a Multiset. The advantage here is that you only have to do register the custom deserialiser once, rather than having to know everywhere to first use an ArrayList type.

This custom deserialiser looks like this:

```
private static class MultisetDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Multiset<?>> {
    @Override
    public Multiset<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        Type[] typeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();

        ParameterizedType listType = new ListParameterizedType(typeArguments);
        List<?> list = context.deserialize(json, listType);

        return HashMultiset.create(list);
    }
}
```

In short, this casts the expected type to deserialise to (e.g. `new TypeToken<Multiset<String>>(){}.getType()` in your case) to [`ParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) to get at the type arguments (String in your example). It then creates a new ParameterizedType which is the type of an ArrayList with the same type arguments (shown below). After using the context to deserialise the JSON to this new type, all you have to do is call `HashMultiset.create`.

The `ListParameterizedType` looks like this:

```
private static class ListParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {
    private final Type[] typeArguments;

    private ListParameterizedType(Type[] typeArguments) {
        this.typeArguments = typeArguments;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return typeArguments;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you could replace `ArrayList` with pretty much any list class here, as long as it has one type argument and a default constructor.

There may also be easier ways to achieve the same thing, for example you could do some of the parsing manually by inspecting the `JsonElement` with its methods like `isJsonArray()`. This could save you from creating an ArrayList which you throw away immediately afterwards.

Comment: This, effectively, is what I have done (in not so neat a code, though).

Comment: @ChthonicProject Have a look at my updated answer, it turns out this is much easier than I thought since all you need to do is define how to create a Multiset.